# Hadoop streaming accessing map-created files from reducer on hdfs

Tags: python, hdfs, hadoop-streaming

I have a hadoop streaming program which calls an external binary in the mapper.  This binary generates and writes out some csv files. Then passes on the file name to the reducer. There is one reduce task that aggregates the files created by the mapper.  I have been able to run the jobs successfully when I use

```
-jobconf mapred.job.tracker=local \
-jobconf fs.defualt.name=local \
```

and run the job on one node in the cluster.  If I run the job on more than one node, it hangs during the reduce step (which I think is being caused by map tasks writing some files on a different node that the reduce task) and if I try to run the job without local jobs tracker all I get is `Streaming Job Failed`

My question is how can I make sure that the reduce task can see all of the files or perhaps make sure the map tasks all write to the reducer's location?

I'm having trouble wrangling HDFS, so any advice will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my map script:
map.py:

```
#! /util/python/2.7.6/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
import subprocess as sp

#mapper
partmc = './partmc'
for line in sys.stdin:
    spec = line.strip().split('\t')[0] # eg, run_3.spec
    args = [partmc, spec]
    sp.Popen(args) #eg, ./partmc run_3.spec
```

And my Hadoop Streaming .sh:

```
    module load python/2.7.6-statsmodels-0.5.0
    $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR jar   $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-0.20.1-streaming.jar \
    -file /user/thomasef/pop/mapreduce/1_urban_plume/map.py \
    -file /user/thomasef/pop/mapreduce/1_urban_plume/reduce.py \
    -file /user/thomasef/pop/mapreduce/1_urban_plume/run_1.spec \
    -file /user/thomasef/pop/mapreduce/1_urban_plume/run_2.spec \
    -file /user/thomasef/pop/mapreduce/1_urban_plume/run_3.spec \
    -file /user/thomasef/pop/mapreduce/1_urban_plume/partmc \
    -file /user/thomasef/pop/mapreduce/1_urban_plume/spec_list.txt \
    -input /user/thomasef/pop/mapreduce/1_urban_plume/spec_list.txt \
    -output /user/thomasef/pop/mapreduce/1_urban_plume/houtput/ \
    -mapper /user/thomasef/pop/mapreduce/1_urban_plume/map.py \
    -reducer /user/thomasef/pop/mapreduce/1_urban_plume/reduce.py \
    -jobconf mapred.job.tracker=local \
    -jobconf fs.defualt.name=local \
    -verbose \
    -numReduceTasks 1
```